# Bootstrap 3 collapsable navbar not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default drop-shadow navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                    <%= image_tag "logo.png", class: "img-responsive" %>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact-us">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am using Rails 4 with the Bootstrap-Sass gem (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to include everything:

Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

When I view my site on a mobile device the collapsed navbar does not appear

Comment: Your code seems to work fine... see this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IxNHhoTpcP#)

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but the bootstrap example includes the `collapsed` class on the navbar toggle, like `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" `